# How to stop JFileChooser from being closed when approve or cancel button is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I use method showOpenDialog of JFileChooser to open file.

How to attach ActionListener to Approve button of `JFileChooser` and how to stop this dialog
from closing after Approve button is clicked and listener completed.

For now I have :

```
public class MainFileChooser extends JFileChooser {

    private FileFilter plainFilter;

    public MainFileChooser() {

        super.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        super.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        plainFilter = new PlainFilter();
        }

public int showOpenFileDialog() {
        ActionListener actionListener = null;
        // JDialog openFileDialog = super.createDialog(getParent());
        super.addActionListener(actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                File[] selectedFiles = MainFileChooser.this.getSelectedFiles();
                for (File file : selectedFiles) {
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(), file.getName() + " does not exist!",
                                "File is not found", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        super.setFileFilter(plainFilter);
        int userOption = super.showOpenDialog(MainFrame.getInstance().getMainFrame());
        super.removeActionListener(actionListener);
        return userOption;

    }
```

Method `showOpenFileDialog` brings up a dialog and when I press Approve button `actionListener` is called and if file doesn't exist then error message is popped up.

But JFileChooser is closing anyway. I want JFileChooser to stay opened if file doesn't exist !

Thank you!

Comment: Check the new answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the `approveSelection()` method to check if the file exists:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class FileChooserSave
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser( new File(".") )
        {
            public void approveSelection()
            {
                if (getSelectedFile().exists())
                {
                    super.approveSelection();
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
            }
        };

        chooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        });

        chooser.setSelectedFile( new File("something.txt") );
        int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);


        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
           System.out.println(chooser.getSelectedFile() );
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please upvote my question because I need 15 reputation to upvote others.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void approveSelection(){
    for(File f : this.getSelectedFiles())
        if(!f.exists()) {
            //Show warning to user
            //if needed: cancelSelection();
            return;
        }              
    super.approveSelection();
}
```

Comment: No listener is needed ;).

Comment: But I need JFileChooser to stay opened after Approve button is pressed

Comment: Ok, just curious, why do you need to JFileChooser to stay opened?

Comment: To make user understand that this file doesn't exist and new one can be chosen.